# I tryed to do stairCase problem with n stairs and 1or2or3 steps at a time But my solution is working fine until 13 after that not, its giving less

Tags: java, logic

```
public class StairCase {
    public static int Solution(int n) {
        int sum, count = 0;
//Funtion to calculate stair case and use factorial because a solution can have many ways.
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
                    sum = i + (j * 2) + (k * 3);
                    if (sum == n) {
                        count = count + (fact.fact1(i + j + k) / (fact.fact1(i) * fact.fact1(j) * fact.fact1(k)));
                    }
                }
            }
```

/*logic behind this funtion is that like we have to find no of arrangement abbbccde can we written so we write (8!/(3!*2!))
so after getting like ijk= 1,2,3 I rearranged them in that man ways
(i+j+k)!/i!*j!*k!  !=factorial*/

```
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void doTestPass() {

        boolean result = true;
        result = result && (Solution(3) == 4);
        result = result && (Solution(4) == 7);
        result = result && (Solution(11) == 504);
        result = result && (Solution(12) == 927);
        result = result && (Solution(13) == 1705);
//working fine till 13 not after that
        System.out.println(Solution(14));
        System.out.println(Solution(20));
        System.out.println(Solution(21));

//14--3127 20--68603 21--94351(orignal ans-- 3136,121415,223317)

        if (result) {
            System.out.println("All Test Cases Passed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test Case Failed");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        doTestPass();
    }
```

public class fact

{

```
 static int fact1(int n)

{
```

//this funtion is to create factorial

```
    int res = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
```

{

```
        res = res * i;
```

}

```
   return res;

}
```

}

```
}
```

Comment: What is `fact.fact1`, `fact` is not included in your code anywhere.

Comment: sry i just corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with using primitive integers for your factorial method and overflowing the integer limit of `2,147,483,647`.

Take a look at trial runs of your factorial code below:

`fact1(12)` outputs `479001600` which *is* correct for `12!`

`fact1(13)` outputs `1932053504` which is *not* `13!` which *should* be `6227020800`

This means when you execute `fact.fact1(i)` in your code, it will be outputting the wrong answer for any value greater than `12`.  This would require you to rework the data structure you use to hold these big numbers to `BigInteger`.

The reworked `fact` method would look like this:

```
BigInteger fact1(int n) {
    // this funtion is to create factorial
    BigInteger res = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        res = res.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    return res;
}
```

With the output of `fact1(13)` being the correct value of `6227020800` now.

You will need to rework the other aspects of your code now with `BigInteger`, but you should understand now what your issue was.

Comment: broo thank you soo much man it worked like charm....i did silly mistake never knew it could go so big....